# DTO-s with less boiler-code for Intent/Parcable/Bundle/SharedPreferences possible?

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, dry, parcelable

I have an app that uses a DTO class `MyAppData` with 21 attributes to be

- transfered via Intent via Parcable between activities,
- saved/restored via Bundle in case of rotation and
- persisted via SharedPreferences(.Editor) if the app is restarted later

I had to write a lot of boiler-code to implement this functionality.

My Question: Is there a simpler way with less boiler-code to achive my goal?

Why this boiler-code?

- Implementing interface `Parcelable` is neccessary to transfer as Intent between activities.
- SharedPreferences(.Editor) to survice app-restart: i found no way to load/save Parcable therefore i had to write extra code for it
- Fourtunately Bundle can load/save `Parcelable`

The boiler-code looks like this

```
    public class MyAppData implements Parcelable {

/****** here is the data that i want to use ******************/

        private String path = null;
        // ... 20 more attibutes

        public String getPath() {return path;}
        public void setPath(String path) {this.path = path;}
        // ... 20 more attibutes

/****** here start a lot of boiler-code necessary to handle the data ******************/

        /********** code needed to implement interface Parcelable *************/
        public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyAppData> CREATOR
                = new Parcelable.Creator<MyAppData>() {
            public MyAppData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new MyAppData(in);
            }

            public MyAppData[] newArray(int size) {
                return new MyAppData[size];
            }
        };

        public MyAppData() {};
        private MyAppData(Parcel in) {
            setPath(in.readString());
            // ... 20 more attibutes
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(getPath());
            // ... 20 more attibutes
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {return 0;}

        /************ code neccessary to handle SharedPreferences(.Editor) because SharedPreferences cannot handle Parcable ********/

         private static final String SHARED_KEY_Path         = "filter_Path";
            // ... 20 more attibutes

        public void saveSettings(SharedPreferences.Editor edit) {

            if (edit != null) {
                edit.putString(SHARED_KEY_Path, this.getPath());
                // ... 20 more attibutes
            }
        }

        public void loadSettings(SharedPreferences sharedPref) {
            if (sharedPref != null) {
                this.setPath(sharedPref.getString(SHARED_KEY_Path, this.getPath()));
                // ... 20 more attibutes
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code that uses MyAppData and its boiler-code

```
MyAppData mMyData;

// to survive recreate on rotation
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.mMyData.saveInstanceState(this, savedInstanceState);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

// to survive recreate on rotation or remember settings on last app start
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    this.mMyData.loadSettingsAndInstanceState(this, savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
protected void onPause () {
    ...
    this.mMyData.saveSettings(this);
}

// to pass to some other activity
private void openSomeActivity() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(context,
            SomeActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_FILTER, filter);

    context.startActivityForResult(intent, 0815);
}

// to receive from some other activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
                                final int resultCode, final Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 0815 :
            myData = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_FILTER);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by implementing a string representation of the dto: having a `toString()` and a `parse()` method to convert between dto and string.

This way

- transfered via Intent between activities,
- saved/restored via Bundle in case of rotation and
- persisted via SharedPreferences(.Editor) if the app is restarted later

is all handled through string